# value in field different from past

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I have a problem with send_keys in selenium. I'm passing a number to a field of a record. In the code, the number is correct, but when selenium types it, the number comes out different from what is in the variable. Has anyone ever experienced this?
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnQ5P.png)
[record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkIdu.png)

I tried to uninstall and update the selenium library but I had the problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a
question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the text box is automatically formatting the string as you are typing it. This seems to be to match the expected format of CNPJ strings.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNPJ

You should manually verify this behavior in browser but this seems to be desired behavior of the website you are automating and not an issue with your code or selenium